# Setting up different invoice number sequence for multi store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, invoice

How would I get two stores in a magento installation to start with same invoicing numbers for ex both stores should have invoive numbers starting from 100, since they both are different stores they should increment independently based on the orders in each store

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-order-number.html Checked this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is change their increment order, you can find them in the `eav_entity_store` table:

[image: eav_entity_store]

**6** corresponds to the invoice type (orders are *5*). You can set a different `increment_prefix` for each of your stores.

Comment: I did not completely understand, so say for the entity_type_id 6, I have two store_id's 1 and 2, now for the store id 1, if I add an increment_prefix as 5, all new invoices on store id 1 will start with 5(for ex 5100013109)?

Comment: Exactly. And your Invoices for store 2 will use the other (default) prefix.

Comment: Thanks @julien Lachal. One last question, would the prefix take in alphabet also?

Comment: The field is a `varchar` so you could in theory set it to be alphabetical, but I haven't tested it, let me know how this works ;) I haven't looked through Magento files to know what's happening at the time of incrementing the value. Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below link and you can easily do this.

http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/